# Check if element is a subset of another in the same multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays

I need to check if each array is a subset of another array of a different shape within the same list of arrays. I need it to return all the indexes of the elements that are subsets.

So far, I have

```
array = [[1,2,3,4],
         [2,3],
         [1,5,7,8],
         [5],
         [7,8],
         [1,2,3],
         [7,8,9]]

#we need to keep [0,2,6]
#we need to remove [1,3,4,5]

    boole = []
    d ={}
    for i,m in enumerate(array):
      d[i] = []
      for j in array:
        boole.append(set(m).issubset(j))

    boole= np.array(boole).reshape(len(array),len(array))


  res = [] #spheres to remove
  for i,m in enumerate(boole):
    if sum(m) > 1: #if the index IS a subset of any other index (excludes "True" identity of itself)
      res.append(i)
  print(res)    

output>>> [1,3,4,5]
```

However I now have a multidimensional array and these this to work for:

```
a = [np.array([[1,2],[1,5],[2,3],[5,7]]),
     np.array([[2,3],[5,7]]),
     np.array([[1,5],[4,5],[9,2]]),
     np.array([[2,3],[4,5],[1,5]]),
     np.array([[2,3],[5,7],[1,5]])]
```

But this throws an error because the issubset() function does not work on multidimensional arrays. I need this to return [1,4] (aka row 1 and row 4). How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `a` supposed to be `array`?

Comment: When exactly would you consider a `np.array` to be a "subset" of another? When they share the same elements in any location? If the array can be found as a slice of the other, even in the middle of rows and columns? If the arrays contain the same rows? There is no function like `issubset()` because the problem can be defined in many ways - you need to specify when you consider an array to be part of/inside another.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
row_remove = []
for i, ai in enumerate(a):
    for j, aj in enumerate(a):
        found = True
        for item in ai.tolist():
            if not (i != j and item in aj.tolist()):
                found = False
                break
        if found:
            row_remove.append(i)
            break
```

When applied on your example array `a`, this gives:

```
print(row_remove) 
[1, 4]
```

The algorithm works like this: Loop over all rows, take every `item` in the row, which is an `np.array`, and check if the other row contains that item. If one `item` was not found, then the row is not a subset of the other row, otherwise, it is a subset and add it to the `row_remove` list.